# How can I qsub a bash script in a job array varying its parameters stored in a array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, jobs, qsub

I have a script which I want to execute with several different arguments, I've got an array that contains all the parameter(argument) combinations `${array[i]}`. 
I want to be able to submit a job array using all the different argument stored in the array:

```
arr_length=${#submittions[@]}
qsub -t 1-$arr_length myscript <*>
```

*Here, I want to use the values of -t to go through my array and use the different parameters stored in it here, I don't know is it is possible.

I have read that there is a built in variable $SGE_TASK_ID.

The array contain from two to seven file paths separated by one space and an amount of arr_length elements in the array. which will be the arguments for the python script.

Comment: Worked for me:
I *qsubbed* a bash script with the parameter `-t 1-$arr_length` containing all the stuff needed to generate the *array* again, and then you can use $SGE_TASK_ID which is going to take the values mentioned before in the parameter -t. Then I just did: python mypyscript.py ${array[$SGE_TASK_ID]}

The problem was I wanted to use the built-in variable $SGE_TASK_ID in the qsub command, which you can't.

Answer (score 2):

`${!array[@]}` never contains the values of the elements in the array. The contain only the indices. For the array elements use `"${array[@]}"` in your script as

```
qsub -t 1-${arr_length} myscript "${array[@]}"
```

E.g.

```
array=('foo' 'bar' 'dude')
printf '%s\n' "${!array[@]}"
0
1
2
```

and see the output of

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: yeah, I understand, I couldn't explain it better, that's the problem. I want to use the sequence in the option -t 1-len_array to be go through my array values and submit it as a job array. Sorry, I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: @Tamalero: Can you specify with more examples (e.g. sample values for array) and your command